# Delete selected rows from HTML Tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to delete selected rows (via checkbox) but I don't understand where I am going wrong

this is my code

JQuery

```
$("#delete").click(function(){
    $("table input[type ='checkbox']:checked").parent().parent().remove();
});
```

HTML

```
<div class = "patientData">
    <div class ="searchBar">
        <input type = "search" name = "search" class = "search">
        <a href="#"><i class ="fa fa-search"></i></a>
        <button id = "delete">Delete Selected</button>
    </div>
    <table style ="width:95%" class = "Info">
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="select"> </th>
            <th> Name</th>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The user enters the rows which is why my table by default only has headings. I have stuck on this for a while now and no research is helping me solving the problem.

Please help if anyone can, Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's not working?  Your code appears to work correctly at http://jsfiddle.net/0a37tbmj/, at least the header row is being removed.  Are you getting anything in your developer console?

Comment: Yup. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/0a37tbmj/2

Comment: what isnt working the way you want it to work?

Comment: For some reason, it does not work on the web page - I don't understand how it works on jsfiddle and there is nothing in the console either

Comment: did you include a reference to the jQuery library in your html?

Comment: Are you sure you're loading jQuery correctly?  What happens in the console if you just type console.log($('#delete'))?  Are you dynamically generating the table from JavaScript?  If that's the case, you'll need to use the "on" method from jQuery to attach the event to a dynamic object.

Comment: When I try console.log($(#delete)); I get this

Comment: @user4538609, i think you missed the end of your last comment

Comment: When I try console.log($("#delete")); I get this [context:document, selector: '#delete', jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function...]

Comment: Ok, next troubleshooting step - to see if the click is being called, put a console.log('testing'); inside the click function.  If that's not being called, you will want to use ssube's function, which might help, since that is using the 'on' method.

Comment: @BrianHoover you are right the click function is not being called, which is why "testing" is not printing to the console

Comment: @BrianHoover ssube's answer doesn't work for me, maybe cos he has table elements (td) where in my case the user adds them. I am getting an error in the td > input line

Comment: I FOUND THE ERROR, I only needed to add $(document).ready(function(){

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector to get all rows containing a checked box, rather than working your way back up to the parent. This will keep the selector at the row-level, preventing DOM changes from accidentally working up too many parents and deleting large chunks of the page.

Something like:

```js
$("#delete-button").on("click", function(e) {
  $("#delete-table tr:has(td > input[type=checkbox]:checked)").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="delete-button">Delete!</button>
<table id="delete-table">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </th>
    <th>Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Row 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @indubitablee It may be, but using `.parent().parent().remove()` on a selector is pretty brittle and could remove the wrong elements in the future. Using `:has` or even `.has` is more correct, as it selects rows, filters ones which contain a checked box, then removes the rows (it never works back up the DOM).

Comment: i agree with that, but OP's issue isnt with the js code itself, which is what your answer is addressing

Comment: Might want to add another type of identifier to the selector. With this if the `checkbox` in the `th` is selected it will also be removed. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/b1g99qfp/)

Comment: do you think the parent().parent().remove() is what might be causing it to not work on the website?

Comment: @ssube What have you rephrased?